# How to trim or format the HH:MM:SS.ms value in Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query in Oracle SQL that displays results as follows:

**SQL:**

```
select 
  uuid, name, 
  to_char(from_tz(startdate, 'UTC') at time zone 'America/New_York', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as startdate_et, 
  to_char(from_tz(enddate, 'UTC') at time zone 'America/New_York', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as enddate_et, 
  (enddate - startdate) as executiontime
from      
  process 
where 
  name = (select name from jobconfiguration where currentprocessid = 'bGd_AAABNaMAAAFQHvY0UyTa');
```

**Output:**
[image]

The problem here is the data in the `executiontime` column. The milliseconds value is too long and also I would like to remove the `+00` from the beginning and trim the `02.951000` to `02.95` and `03.284000` to `03.28`.

Please guide.

Comment: What are the datatypes of `STARTDATE` and `ENDDATE`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between two timestamps is an interval.  By default, this includes long fractions of the second.

For printing purposes, just use `to_char()`:

```
to_char(fenddate - startdate, 'dd hh24:mi:ss') as executiontime
```

Because the default for the difference is an interval of "day to second", you only need to include these elements.

Answer (score 0):

The difference of two timestamps is already well formatted and being printed in the format 
*+/-number of days hours:minutes:seconds.milliseconds*

Why don't you want the +00, is it because it is 0 days? 
I am assuming you would want it if the days difference is greater than zero?

Anyway it is easier to use *substr* to format the output as needed and use case when on number of days.

For example
**substr(start_time-end_time, instr(start_time-end_time, '.')+1, 2)** to trim milliseconds to two digits.

and 
**case when to_number(substr(start_time-end_time, 1, instr(start_time-end_time, ' '))) > 0 then substr(start_time-end_time, 1, instr(start_time-end_time, ' ')) else '' end**
to get number of days

or **substr(start_time-end_time, instr(start_time-end_time, ' '))** to remove the days completely